# Ionic Not working in safari but works in crome and android phone

Tags: ionic-framework

I am debugging my app.
it works well in crome and my note3 phone. 
but If I test in safari, 
login page doesn't change to dashboard page after login but token and Id is in localStorage it just stays in login page(1). 
and form gets all messed up when keyboard appears. also it doesn't looks like it follows responsive web design that I gave(2).

- could solve it when I don't use location.reload() in last part of my login function after $state.go('app.dashboard') but then when I am in dashboard and click menu then it doesn't bring all the data. but if I reload menually again then it loads up and samething happens in crome.
- I don't know why it does do this at all

Comment: Please try to run with terminal: ionic build ios and then ionic run ios

Comment: and please try to change location of project.